# Switch Case inside JQueryUI Dialog Option:Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

what i want to achieve is to show the buttons in my JQueryUI Dialog based on the condition i want. How to do it? this is what i have done so far but it is not working. Any problem with my code? Any help please..

```
var _messageBoxButtons = 0 

$("#Dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    zIndex: 100000,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function () {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    },
    title: "Testing Title",
    buttons: function()
    {
        switch(_messageBoxButtons)
        {
            case 0:
                return {
                    "OK": function (event) { }
                };
            case 1:
                return {
                    "Yeah": function (event) { }
                };
        }
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

jquery ui buttons can take an object or array of objects. It can't take a function. Just create the object or object array based on your var:

```
var _messageBoxButtons = 0 
switch(_messageBoxButtons)
    {
        case 0:
            var buttonsObjectArray = [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }}];
        case 1:
            var buttonsObjectArray = [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }},{ text: "Yeah", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" );}}];
    }
```

Then put that in your dialog:

```
....
title: "Testing Title",
buttons:  buttonsObjectArray
....
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qe9p7/ You can swap out the vars in the fiddle to see it with one or two buttons.

[jquery ui dialog documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons)